# Replacing only first _ character from filename using Batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

First of all, the batch file should work only in whichever folder I copy it in.

For example, I have a filename like this ;

TEST2-FILE-REPLACE_05_07

I want this filename to change as below. It will just replace the first "_" character with "+". Other _ will stay the same

TEST2-FILE-REPLACE+05_07

Can someone tell me how to do this? The code below works but makes all "underline" characters "+". I just want it to make the first "underline" character "+".

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*_*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_=M!"
)
```

Comment: The best way to do it is to stop using `cmd` and start using `powershell` :-) Such as with https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rename-multiple-files-bulk-windows-10#rename-files-using-powershell. If uou must use `cmd`, download a third party tool to make your life easier (such as `prename`).

Comment: The above code works but it changes all the underlines I want it to change only the first one


Thank you for the method you gave but there will be hundreds of files each time I need to change it this way. If I can do it with one click with the method I have given above, I will save a lot of time.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%G in ('dir /a-d /b *_*') do ren "%%G_%%H" "%%G+%%H"`

Comment: @Squashman Than you very much! thats what I need!

Comment: @paxdiablo, It is a bit extreme to suggest a third party tool when you can simply utilize `tokens` in a `for` loop?

Comment: @Gerhard: only if you consider that monstrosity more readable than the equivalent `prename` :-)

Comment: I will offer a compromise to both of you and say to use Dbenham's [jren.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081)

Answer (score 0):

There are the following issues in your code:

1. [Sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) syntax replaces all occurrences of a search string, so it is the wrong approach. With a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) however, you can split strings at certain delimiters.
2. A [standard `for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) does not build the whole list of files in advance, hence files may become renamed twice. Therefore, use [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to build the whole file list first and then process it with [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).
3. Since you have got [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled all the time, `!` and `^` may become lost. Avoiding delayed expansion or wisely toggling it prevents that.
4. When the script is executed a second time, already processed files are going to be processed again, so the next `_` is going to be replaced. Thus, defining a condition to exclude such files is advisable. You could for example use [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to exclude all files that already have got a `+` in their names.

Here is a possible fixed code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\path\to\target\location" & rem // (full path to target directory)
set "_MASK="*_*.*"                     & rem // (pattern to match files against)
set "_CHAR=_"                          & rem // (character to become replaced)
set "_REPL=+"                          & rem // (character used for replacement)
set "_FILT=^[^%_REPL%]*$"              & rem // (exclusion filter for `findstr`)

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Iterate through all matching non-hidden and non-system files with exclusions:
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=%_CHAR% eol=%_CHAR%" %%I in ('
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%_MASK%" ^| findstr /I "%_FILT%"
    ') do (
        rem // Actually rename the currently iterated file (no delayed expansion here):
        if exist "%%I%_CHAR%%%J" ren "%%I%_CHAR%%%J" "%%I%_REPL%%%J"
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script would skip files whose names begin with `_` and such whose first occurrence of `_` is immediately followed by another `_`.